# Unable to develop body for email in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have written a stored procedure where "i have to compare values in two tables and send mail to the users which are not present in second table.

I have to automate this report .

But issue comes when i am trying to make mail body for the same.

The mail body is to be taken from table `record` ie column name `REQ_Approval_EMAILBODY`.Also the `Recipient id` has to be taken from table records ie cloumn name `REQ_Approval_EMAILID`.

This query has to execute for all the records one by one with respective email ID from table.

Please help me to sort out his.

Thanks in advance

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Email_Daily
AS

BEGIN
DECLARE @bodynew VARCHAR(Max)

DECLARE @query1 VARCHAR(Max)

DECLARE @Para VARCHAR(Max)

DECLARE @query2 VARCHAR(Max)

DECLARE @query3 VARCHAR(Max)

DECLARE @query5 VARCHAR(Max)



DECLARE     @Yesterday VARCHAR(50)
SET         @Yesterday = REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(50),GETDATE()-1,102),'.','-') 


DECLARE     @TODAY_DDMMYYY VARCHAR(50)
SET         @TODAY_DDMMYYY = REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(50),GETDATE()-1,6),' ','-') 



SELECT  * into #Temp3_New_Table
FROM(
SELECT [MessageIdentifier]
      ,[MessageIdentifier_Archive]
      ,CONVERT(DATE,REQ_SentDate) AS REQ_SentDate
      ,[REQ_Token]
      ,[REQ_Approval_Number]
      ,[REQ_Order_Number]
      ,[REQ_Document_Number]
      ,[REQ_Approval_EMAILID]
      ,[REQ_Approval_EMAILBODY]
      ,[REQ_Approval_EMAIL_Subject]
      ,[RES_Date]
      ,[IsValid]
      ,[Response_MessageIdentifier]
      ,[ReSubmit_Count]
      ,'0' as Flag
  FROM [SAEI].[dbo].[Approval_EMAIL_LOG] 
  where CONVERT(DATE,REQ_SentDate) = @Yesterday
  and res_date is null
  and req_approval_number+req_order_number+req_document_number not in
  (SELECT 
      [RES_Approval_Number]+[RES_Order_Number]+[RES_Document_Number] 
  FROM [SAEI].[dbo].[Approval_Response_WEB_LOG]))as Tr



set @query5='select * from #Temp3_New_Table'


set @para='<p style="font-family:arial; font-size:14px">
            Dear Team,
            </br>
            </br>

            </br>
         </p>'




Set @bodynew = @PARA 


DECLARE @subjects       VARCHAR(200)

DECLARE @FileAttachment VARCHAR(400)

DECLARE @Recipients     VARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE @copy           VARCHAR(MAX)


set @Recipients='select [REQ_Approval_EMAILID] from #Temp3_New_Table'


        drop table #Temp3_New_Table       
End
```

Comment: what is the desired output?

Comment: Output comes out to be right..three columns not present in table B.But i need to take email body from the record and display it in mail..Also the email id has to be taken from record itself

Comment: It is unclear what your requirement is. What part of your provide code do you need assistance with?

Comment: @stephen-I need to display the column named [REQ_Approval_EMAILBODY] in set@para

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select @para = concat('<p style="font-family:arial; font-size:14px">Dear Team,</br></br>', [REQ_Approval_EMAILBODY],'</br></p>')
from #Temp3_New_Table 
{where condition}
```

**EDIT**
if you want a cursor then you can try this

```
DECLARE evilCurse CURSOR FOR
    SELECT [REQ_Approval_EMAILID]
          ,[REQ_Approval_EMAILBODY] = concat('<p style="font-family:arial; font-size:14px">Dear Team,</br></br>', [REQ_Approval_EMAILBODY],'</br></p>')
          ,[REQ_Approval_EMAIL_Subject]
      FROM [SAEI].[dbo].[Approval_EMAIL_LOG] 
      where CONVERT(DATE,REQ_SentDate) = @Yesterday
      and res_date is null
      and req_approval_number+req_order_number+req_document_number not in
            (SELECT [RES_Approval_Number]+[RES_Order_Number]+[RES_Document_Number] 
            FROM [SAEI].[dbo].[Approval_Response_WEB_LOG])

OPEN evilCurse
FETCH NEXT FROM evilCurse
INTO @Recipients, @bodynew, @subjects
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    --do what ever you want to do to here 

    FETCH NEXT FROM evilCurse
    INTO @Recipients, @bodynew, @subjects
END

CLOSE evilCurse;
DEALLOCATE evilCurse;
```

Comment: @stephen-Also i need to set cursor for the same..Could you help to do the same.??

Comment: @stephen-i need to run this query for multiple records. I mean the email id and mail body has to be taken from select query itslef where a mail would be sent to forst record then second and so on..till last